# Extending Band size in jasper at design time

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jaspersoft studion plugin in eclipse and designing a report.
I have so many object(graphs,text,tables) to fill into report.jrxml. I have also set the page size(A4) and because of that band size is limited and I am not able to increase the band size anymore.
I have attached the screenshot of the report.
It would be great help if somebody could tell how to put more object into band.

Screenshot of the Jaspersoft Studio:
[image: Screenshot of the jaspersoft studio]

Comment: Got it, we just need to add a new Detail Band

Comment: You could also use subreports.